# WP Full Calendar Changing the Event URL

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, fullcalendar

I am using WP Full Calendar and Event Manager Plugin for Wordpress.
The calendar currently links to the single event url, however I want it to link to the #_BOOKINGSLINK placeholder (the admin page for management).
Is this possible to do?
I found code for the function file that removes the URL, but I am unsure of how to code the placeholder with PHP, as I am a beginner.

Is anyone able to assist me? Many thanks in advance.

Code That Removes URL from calendar:

```
function my_fc_filter( $events ){
  foreach($events as $key => $event){
    unset($events[$key]['url']);
  }
  return $events;
}
add_filter('wpfc_events','my_fc_filter');
```

Comment: What happens if instead of `unset` you do `$events[$key]['url'] = 'https://ANYTHING.com/#_BOOKINGSLINK';`??

Comment: @brasofilo - thank you so much! This has worked.